# aiohttp - before request for each API call

Tags: python, python-asyncio, swagger-ui, aiohttp, connexion

**When I was using Flask, every API call is authenticated before processed:**

```
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/', swagger_json=True, swagger_ui=True, server='tornado')
app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'ABCD API'})
# add CORS support
CORS(app.app)
```

```
@app.app.before_request
def before_request_func():
    app_id = request.headers.get("X-AppId")
    token = request.headers.get("X-Token")
    user, success = security.Security().authorize(token)
    if not success:
        status_code = 401
        response = {
            'code': status_code,
            'message': 'Unauthorized user'
        }
        return jsonify(response), status_code
    g.user = user
```

**When I changed it to AioHttp, my authentication is not properly setup:**

```
options = {'swagger_path': 'swagger/', "swagger_ui": True}
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/', options=options)
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': ' ABCD API'})
app = web.Application(middlewares=[auth_through_token])
```

```
async def auth_through_token(app: web.Application, handler: Any) -> Callable:
    @web.middleware
    async def middleware_handler(request: web.Request) -> web.Response:
        headers = request.headers
        x_auth_token = headers.get("X-Token")
        app_id = headers.get("X-AppId")
        user, success = security.Security().authorize(x_auth_token)
        if not success:
            return web.json_response(status=401, data={
                "error": {
                    "message": ("Not authorized. Reason: {}"
                                )
                }
            })
        response = await handler(request)
        return response

    return middleware_handler
```

My request is not getting redirected to the API method.

Could anyone please help me to set up, my before_request authentication for every API?
Thanks.

Comment: for me it looks like you can use `middleware_handler` in a list of middlewares. If you don't want to do that - you need to call it from `auth_through_token`. But haven't checked. Let me know if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to move *middleware_handler* out from *auth_through_token*.

Then,
Quote your code:

```
options = {'swagger_path': 'swagger/', "swagger_ui": True}
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/', options=options)
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': ' ABCD API'})
app = web.Application(middlewares=[auth_through_token])
```

You have to **remove the last line** and change the first line to:

```
options = {'swagger_path': 'swagger/', "swagger_ui": True, 'middlewares': [middleware_handler]}
```

So finally the code should look like:

```
options = {'swagger_path': 'swagger/', "swagger_ui": True, 'middlewares': [middleware_handler]}
app = connexion.AioHttpApp(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/', options=options)
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': ' ABCD API'})

@web.middleware
async def middleware_handler(request: web.Request, handler: Any) -> web.Response:
    headers = request.headers
    x_auth_token = headers.get("X-Token")
    app_id = headers.get("X-AppId")
    user, success = security.Security().authorize(x_auth_token)
    if not success:
        return web.json_response(status=401, data={
            "error": {
                "message": ("Not authorized. Reason: {}"
                            )
            }
        })
    response = await handler(request)
    return response
```